# Client [/mir_auto_bagger] wants topic /move_base/goal to have datatype/md5sum

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to do a gmapping with my mobile robot an error pop-up:

```
[ERROR] [1554797108.240628800]: Client [/mir_auto_bagger] wants topic /move_base/goal to have datatype/md5sum [*/8ac6f5411618f50134619b87e4244699], but our version has [move_base_msgs/MoveBaseActionGoal/660d6895a1b9a16dce51fbdd9a64a56b]. Dropping connection.

[move_base_node-2] process has died [pid 6194, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/move_base/move_base cmd_vel:=mobile_base/commands/velocity __name:=move_base_node __log:=/home/chbloca/.ros/log/ed0463be-5a97-11e9-93e4-94c6911e7b24/move_base_node-2.log]. log file: /home/chbloca/.ros/log/ed0463be-5a97-11e9-93e4-94c6911e7b24/move_base_node-2*.log
```

What library should I modify in order to make the PC messages to be compatible with the mobile robot?
PD: I cannot access to the mobile robot PC

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320638/client-%5B/mir_auto_bagger%5D-wants-topic-/move_base/goal-to-have-datatype/md5sum/) by [chbloca](https://answers.ros.org/users/38830/chbloca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2019-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-09**:
This seems like a cross-post of [dfki-ric/mir_robot#20](https://github.com/dfki-ric/mir_robot/issues/20)?

**Comment by [chbloca](https://answers.ros.org/users/38830/chbloca/) on 2019-04-09**:
It is, indeed

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-09**:
What has changed since you opened that issue?

**Comment by [chbloca](https://answers.ros.org/users/38830/chbloca/) on 2019-04-09**:
Nothing at all. No solutions yet

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-09**:
I believe @Martin Günther's answer on your `mir_robot` issue was pretty OK: either use a ROS version that corresponds to what the robot runs, or use his driver to not work with messages directly.

Alternatively you could see whether using the same `move_base` messages on your PC would work, but it's likely that `move_base` on your own PC will not work with the messages that your robot uses.

**Comment by [chbloca](https://answers.ros.org/users/38830/chbloca/) on 2019-04-09**:
So do you mean that my robot is running under Indigo ROS? Because the ROS in my computer is Kinetic.
I cannot use his bridge since it is not suitable for heavy topics such as the ones that the camera produces.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-09**:
If your robot is running Indigo, then yes, using a client PC running Indigo (or a Docker image) should work.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2019-04-10**:
@gvdhoorn - good catch on finding that GitHub issue, I wouldn't have seen this question if you hadn't mentioned me. Out of curiosity - do you monitor *all* of GitHub? :D

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-10**:\

> Out of curiosity - do you monitor all of GitHub? :D

yes ;)

---

But in reality: most cross-posters just copy-paste whatever they've posted in place "X" verbatim to place "Y". A search for the title of this post here on ROS Answers immediately leads to the GH issue.

**Comment by [chbloca](https://answers.ros.org/users/38830/chbloca/) on 2019-04-10**:
Thank you guys for the support to this topic. Not all heroes wear capes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've posted a full answer to the GitHub issue: https://github.com/dfki-ric/mir_robot/issues/20#issuecomment-481623049

In short, I've updated the MirMoveBase action definition to match the md5sum that's expected by the MiR - this should solve your problem.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2019-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chbloca](https://answers.ros.org/users/38830/chbloca/) on 2019-04-10**:
Thanks Martin.
So his answer was:

I have just updated the mir_actions and mir_msgs packages to the MiR software version 2.3.1. The MirMoveBase action now looks like this:

https://github.com/dfki-ric/mir_robot/blob/7682e991e0efb66b1fcfbf0a4c2b42f9a837235a/mir_actions/action/MirMoveBase.action

This action definition hasn't changed between MiR software versions 1.9.13 and 2.3.1, so as long as you use any MiR software version within that range, you should be ok. In 2.4.0, the action has changed, which causes problems.

If you use this new action definition, the message mir_actions/MirMoveBaseActionGoal has md5sum 8ac6f5411618f50134619b87e4244699, which is exactly what the client wants (see the error message in your first post).

This is what you need to do if you want to send move_base goals to the MiR directly, without using the mir_bridge:

- clone and compile the latest version of this repo
- change your move_base client so that it sends mir_actions/MirMoveBase, ...